# loading a bmp image in visual studio 2008

Tags: .net, visual-c++, opengl

I'm having a problem loading a bmp image as a background texture into my project
the program is having a problem showing it. instead it's showing me a white background
this is how I'm loading it:

```
void makeTexture(char * path,int i)
{   
    teximage[i]=auxDIBImageLoadA(path);
    glGenTextures(i,&tex[i]);
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D,tex[i]);
    glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D,0,3,teximage[i]->sizeX,teximage[i]->sizeY,
        0,GL_RGB, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, teximage[i]->data);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D,GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER,GL_LINEAR);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D,GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER,GL_LINEAR);
    glTexEnvf(GL_TEXTURE_ENV,GL_TEXTURE_ENV_MODE,GL_DECAL);
}
bool setTexture()
{
      //load the images
      memset(teximage,0,sizeof(void *)*1);  //init the array

      makeTexture("6.bmp",0);
      return true;
}
```

Comment: Are the dimensions of `6.bmp` powers of two?

Answer (score 0):

Try setting your filter modes before you upload your pixel data:

```
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D,GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER,GL_LINEAR);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D,GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER,GL_LINEAR);
glTexEnvf(GL_TEXTURE_ENV,GL_TEXTURE_ENV_MODE,GL_DECAL); 
glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, 3, teximage[i]->sizeX, teximage[i]->sizeY, 0, GL_RGB, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, teximage[i]->data);
```

Comment: i tried that. it still doesn't work. it's giving me an error with the x,y size